# VSFTPD change user password

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have got an Ubuntu server 16.04 with **vsftpd** already installed and configured.
and I'm able to access with a user **admin317934**, that is able to browse the whole filesystem.

Now I'd like to restrict the access of this user to a specific folder (that should not be his home but a folder under */var/data/317934*)
And I'd like also to add another user called **user076935**

**I'm not able to understand where the FTP users are set and where I have to go to modify their permissions and passwords.**

The vsfptd.conf file has the following:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=NO
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd_xxxxxxx
chroot_list_enable=YES
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

From the above configuration I see there's no virtual user defined, right?
If I try to list all users with *cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd*
there is no one named **admin317934**

Looking in the file */etc/vsftpd.chroot_list* I can see listed **admin317934** and another one called **admin999546** but without any password specified or home directory.

So which is the right way to configure users for FTP?